# Error: Couldn't resolve extends clause of ./configs/.babelrc

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, babeljs, material-table

Just installed [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/docs/get-started), a framework based on material-ui's Table Component.
This is what i get in console and terminal:
[image: img]
[image: img]

What i tried to do was installing different versions of babel, babel-core, babel-loader, from solutions i found. 
I don't know if this is the issue, the error seems to say so to me.

This is what is relevant from package.json:

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"webpack": "^4.38.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
```

The issue doesn't happen with other React components i have in the app;

It happens for the "getting started" component they provide:

```
import MaterialTable from "material-table";

class ListNew extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
        <MaterialTable
          columns={[
            { title: "Adı", field: "name" },
            { title: "Soyadı", field: "surname" },
            { title: "Doğum Yılı", field: "birthYear", type: "numeric" },
            {
              title: "Doğum Yeri",
              field: "birthCity",
              lookup: { 34: "İstanbul", 63: "Şanlıurfa" }
            }
          ]}
          data={[
            { name: "Mehmet", surname: "Baran", birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 }
          ]}
          title="Demo Title"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ListNew;
```

Webpack config:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./script.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, ""),
    filename: "transpiled.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: "/node_modules/",
        query: {
          presets: ["es2015", "react"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: What is your Webpack config for `babel-loader`?

Comment: Could you try to change to `test: /\.jsx?$/` ?